# Django CSV import data

Tags: python, django, csv

I am quite new in Django so apology in advance if my question sounds unnatural to django world. What I am trying to do is have model in which user can add data by each day or have CSV import field where user can add monthly data in batch.

Example of daily data is like below...

```
class DailyData(models.Model):
    date = models.DateField("Date", blank= True)
    field1 = 
    field2 = 
    etc..
```

so what I am trying is to have model in django where user can add single day data or have import field with csv model where data can be imported for whole month.

what will be best approach to implement this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks for looking into it. but i found what I was after.

http://django-import-export.readthedocs.org/en/latest/getting_started.html

Answer (score 0):

You could create a file upload form where the user can upload his CSV file. Then use the csv module from the standard library (https://docs.python.org/2.7/library/csv.html) to copy the data into your model.